# mysql procedure should return only status to unix script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, unix, stored-procedures

I have a mysql procedure which has out parameter and some print statements for debugging.
I am calling this procedure from Unix shell script, idea is to assign the out parameter to a unix variable, which i use to check in later conditions. But the variable is getting the print statements also getting assigned. I want to get rid of print statements and just only the out parameter (integer) assigned to the variable.

Unix script:

```
output_var=`mysql -sN test_db -e "call delete_me(@outs);select @outs"`
echo $output_var
```

giving print statements as well

```
proc started
proc ended
1043
```

When i run the code in sql client like DBeaver.. i get only the out parameter..

```
call delete_me(@out);select @out
```

```
@out 
----
1043
```

I don't want to suppress print/debug statements, as they are helpful in my logs. but i don't want them in mysql out variable and ultimately in my unix variable as well.

here is mysql procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `delete_me`(out success int)
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE var1 INT;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS;  
        ROLLBACK; 
        SET success=1;
    END;
    START TRANSACTION;
  
    select max(run_id) into var1 from job_run;
    
    select 'proc started';
    
    select 'proc ended';
    
    SET success:= var1;
    
END;
```

Comment: Are the "loading started" and "loading completed" generated from SELECT statements in the procedure body? I don't recognize those as standard MySQL output, so I guess you need to modify the code of the procedure. What answer are you expecting here, given that you have not shared the current procedure code?

Comment: @BillKarwin yes.. (those are my print statements for debugging). I had now added mysql procedure as well. Please suggest.

Comment: the latest update to the question has changed the output from 3 lines to just one line; please confirm what the output looks like ... 3 lines? 1 line?  also, you've mentioned you want the debug lines to go into a log ... please update the question to show how you're currently performing this operation

Comment: @markp-fuso  As I execute the mysql procedure, from a shell script, the variable (output_var) is holding both print statements and integer in a single line. But still when you make tail -1 , it is giving only the last integer. which is perfect. but by doing tail -1, i am missing the print statements. they were never displayed. I run my script using ```nohup sh abc.sh &``` so, i expect those print statements to be present in the nohup.out file as well. otherwise they were no where printed. I am looking for 1)to print the statements and 2)get only the int (success) into output_var variable.

Comment: if the `tail -1` shows only the number then your variable *is* capturing the output as multiple lines; I'm guessing you did something like `echo $output_var` (without double quotes around the variable) which would print everything as a single line; if you run `echo "$output_var"` (double quotes around the variable) then you'll get output across mutiples lines; regardless, I've updated my answer with one approach to appending the debug output to a log file while capturing `@outs` to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- debug statements and `select @out` are displayed on separate lines (as with OP's original question)
- need to append all but the last line to a log file
- last line is to be saved in a variable

We'll start with a copy of OP's current method of capturing all output to a variable:

```
all_output=$(mysql -sN test_db -e "call load_procedure(@out);select @out")

# for demo purposes I'll use:

all_output='proc started
proc ended
1043'
```

To append all but the last line to a log file:

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${all_output}" | head -n -1 >> logfile
$ cat logfile
proc started
proc ended

# sed alternative:

$ printf "%s\n" "${all_output}" | sed '$d' >> logfile
$ cat logfile
proc started
proc ended
```

To capture the last line to a new variable:

```
$ output_var="$(printf "%s\n" "${all_output}" | tail -1)"
$ printf "%s\n" "${output_var}"
1043
```

Comment: Thank you for the hack, but with tail -1, I can able to capture the last value from stdout. but the debug statements are not printed anymore. I am looking to print debug statements in my log and just assign the out parameter to the unix variable.

Answer (score 1):

Since the "debug" statements are outputting to stdout, and the `select @out;` is also outputting to stdout, there's no way the MySQL client can tell them apart. There's no output-redirection feature for procedures.

So you have to think creatively.

One idea would be to make sure your debugging statements have some common pattern so you can filter it out. For example, use the word "#DEBUG" consistently.

```
...
select '#DEBUG: proc started';
...
```

Then filter it when you call it from Bash:

```
output_var=$(mysql -sN test_db 
  -e "call delete_me(@outs); select @outs" 
  | grep -v '#DEBUG')
```

Another idea is to change the code so your debug statements only output conditionally.

```
if @debug then
  select 'proc started';
end if;
```

So you can call it this way if you want debug output:

```
output_var=$(mysql -sN test_db 
  -e "set @debug=1; call delete_me(@outs); select @outs")
```

And just not set `@debug=1` if you don't want debug output.

The bottom line is that MySQL stored procedures are really inconvenient in many cases. No real debugger, no packages, no compiler, no standard library, no atomic deployment, etc. I've been using MySQL for many years, but I have hardly ever seen a good use for procedures.

Comment: Thanks much Bill. so you mean there is no way if i want both at once ? 1.debug statements get printed and 2.out parameter assigned back to unix variable. Because when i use grep to filter non debug statements, I achieve point 2., but not 1.  (Also when i don't want to introduce a new log table and check debugs from that table)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant when I wrote "there's no way" in my answer above. Did you see that?